# MATLAB: difference between getpts(ax) getpts(fig)?

Tags: matlab

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802339/how-can-the-crosshair-of-ginput-be-restricted-to-one-plot), and the answer by Marc, and I can't get the getpts function to work as described. (BTW, I wanted to just comment on Marc's answer, but the site doesn't let me comment until a rep of 50.) According to documentation, and Marc, using

`[x,y] = getpts(ax);`

is supposed to restrict the user's point selection to within the axis, and *prohibit* point selection in the rest of the figure. Right??

Well, if so, it's not working. I'm writing a program in which I want the user to specify a part of the image to chop off. I made a figure with an image via the `imagesc()` command. I then try to do the following:

`set(0,'CurrentFigure',1)` (Because he program has more than one figure open)

`ax = gca;`

`[x,y] = getpts(ax);`

The small cross cursor comes up, and I can click and select points *anywhere in the figure, including in the gray border area outside of the image*. This is exactly the same behavior as I get if I run `[x,y] = getpts(gcf);` So, what's going on here?? Either way, the point selection is allowed in the entire figure window and NOT restricted to just the axis area where my image is...

My Matlab version is R2014a.

Comment: You can look at `x,y` and reject any points that are on on your image, based on the matrix dimensions.